# Перевод плагина при помощи Loco Translate

Tags: wordpress

Использую авторский чужой плагин [ссылка на файлы плагина](https://github.com/Automattic/o2/), который выводит поверх текстов [темы](https://github.com/paulgibbs/p2-breathe), свой текст и функционал комментов.
создаю перевод привычным образом через Loco Translate плагин для вордпресс сайта.  Благо он похож на программу Poedit и работает не хуже.
как обычно на основе pot файла создались 2 файла MO и PO.
перевод готов.
Loco Translate показывает все зелеными галочками. названия файлов с исходным совпадают. все гуд.
проблема в том что тексты на сайте так и остались на английском.
Перепроверял через другие браузеры, очищал кэш и обновлял страницу.
Не показалось. Переводов текста нет.
Что мог упустить из виду что перевод так и остался скрытым?
а упущено то что, нет load_theme_textdomain в плагине. подразумевая что тема должна подтягивать это.
однако проблема осталась не решенной.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78040/discussion-on-question-by-bil-berry-----loco-translate).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб спасибо. Но что странно, система не предложила переместить нашу лапшу из каментов в чат. А то бы я сам, конечно, спрятал.

Comment: @KAGGDesign, зато система призвала модератора)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб что-то не так в консерватории )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в functions.php вашей темы

```
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'o2_load_textdomain' );
function o2_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( 'o2', false, 'o2/languages/' );
}
```

Comment: отобразились. спасибо. но после того как файлы MO и PO загрузил не наравне с папкой плагина/languages где o2.pot файл. а вот сюда wp-content/languages/plugins. именно только 2 файла загрузил бещ лишних подпапок o2-ru_RU.po и o2-ru_RU.mo ////странно как то это действие выглядит.

Comment: Папка плагина у вас как называется?

Comment: папка плагина называется о2

Comment: Странно. Должно работать и из папки languages. Ядро ищет в двух местах: в указанной папке (...o2/languages) и в папке /wp-content/languages/plugins

Comment: Я понял, почему не работает из подпапки плагина. Третий аргумент в load_plugin_textdomain() - путь уже относительно WP_PLUGIN_DIR. Исправил ответ.

Comment: учту. только перевод в папке плагина считается авторским местом хранения. а языки/плагины системным. от этого тоже возможно приоритетность поиска перевода играет роль

Comment: Приоритетность есть. Сначал ядро ищет в /wp-content/languages, потом в относительном пути плагина. Но удобнее хранить в подпапках плагина - для переноса на другой сайт при необходимости. Я уж не говорю о публикации плагина в офциальном репозитории WordPress - там все переводы хранятся в подпапке плагина.

Comment: это верно замечено

Comment: что интересно, но поменяв и перенесы файлы обратно в папку плагина, переводы пропадают все таки. системная папка размещения переводов лучше выдает файлы. но почему так? может после обновления вордпресс системно стали переводы размещаться и читаться иначе. потому что автоматом даже файлы переводов Loco плагина именно в системной папке расположены изначально